# Not adequate behaviour of the BottomSheet

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

During the initialisation of the BottomView part of it appears in the bottom of the screen, when I'm trying to drag it by finger, it appears and then immediately disappear. How to fix it? Or how to make that all items of BottomSheet would appear in the screen, after the FloatActionButton is clicked?

Video of BottomSheet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58bhlc-KfYA&feature=youtu.be

code of Activity:

```
public class FirstscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener,
        ItemAdapter.ItemListener {

    private BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog;
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
    private ItemAdapter mAdapterItem;
    private FloatingActionButton floatButton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front);


        mList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, this));

        mList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        floatButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.float_button);
        floatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showBottomSheetDialog();
            }
        });

        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet;
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                // React to state change
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                // React to dragging events
            }
        });
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAdapterItem = new ItemAdapter(createItems(), this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterItem);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (RecyclerViewAdapter) mList.getAdapter();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void showBottomSheetDialog() {
        if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }

        mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheet, null);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(createItems(), new ItemAdapter.ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Item item) {
                if (mBottomSheetDialog != null) {
                    mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }));

        mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
        mBottomSheetDialog.show();
        mBottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                mBottomSheetDialog = null;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAdapterItem.setListener(null);
    }

    public List<Item> createItems() {
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.camera, "from new shoots"));
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.folder_multiple_image, "from ready images"));
        return items;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Item item) {
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    }
}
```

RecyclerView Adapter inside the BottomSheet:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Item> mItems;
    private ItemListener mListener;

    public ItemAdapter(List<Item> items, ItemListener listener) {
        mItems = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void setListener(ItemListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(mItems.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
        public Item item;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }

        public void setData(Item item) {
            this.item = item;
            imageView.setImageResource(item.getDrawableResource());
            textView.setText(item.getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemClick(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ItemListener {
        void onItemClick(Item item);
    }
}
```

xml of Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#118b0a"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/float_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_white" />


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml of RecyclerView item inside the BottomSheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines of code solved my problem:

```
mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```